# Duplicate WordPress site to subdirectory but use same db?

Tags: theme-development, htaccess, testing

I have tried to just copy the whole root folder into a subdirectory. I understand the .htaccess file has to be changed. But can't get it to work right.

Is it something more than changing the htaccess file I'll have to do to make this possible?

As I said in the question, I want to use the same database. So I can't change any URL's in the database.

**Edit:** I have figured out that the site actually is going in to the directory, but then is redirecting back to the root again. I changed the site's url with `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in wp-config.php-file. But nothing happens, the site is still redirecting back.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

You have to COPY the index.php ot to the root and edit it to add the sub dir path.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you meaning. But I now tried to add sub dir before wp-blog-header.php in index.php but resulted in "`failed to open stream`" errors. The sub dir end up twice, "`/!test/!test/`".